# Select Distinct value in PXSelector

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to select distinct value in PXSelector in Acumatica 5.x?

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<TestTable.Value, Where<TestTable.ID, Equal<Current<CurTable.ID>>>>))]
```

Values in TestTable are free form and can be duplicate.  I would like selector to be able to select without duplicate value.

```
ID      Value
1       Test1
1       Test2
1       Test1
```

Desire Result should show only 'Test1' and 'Test2'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would think you could use Search4 and do an aggregate:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search4<TestTable, Where<TestTable.ID, Equal<Current<CurTable.ID>>>, Aggregate<GroupBy<TestTable.Value>>>))]
```